# htaccess: remove portion of url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

if my URL was:
`http://mywebsite.com/lawyer/my-lawyer-profile`

How would I remove `lawyer` from the URL for all similar requests?

```
RewriteRule ^lawyer/(.+)/$ /$1
```

That doesn't seem to work ... of course, I can access the url as `http://mywebsite.com/my-lawyer-profile` but I need the URL to always rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `[R=301]` flag and get rid of the trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^lawyer/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This makes it so when someone goes to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/lawyer/my-lawyer-profile
```

the browser gets redirected to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/my-lawyer-profile
```

Comment: I need it to automatically change the url from `/lawyer/my-lawyer-profile` to `/my-lawyer-profile/`

Comment: @dcolumbus that's what it does. The browser's URL address bar will say `http://mywebsite.com/my-lawyer-profile`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the proper flags at the end of the command to actually perform the rewrite in the client browser.  So something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^lawyer/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here the `R=301` will provide a 301 FOUND header to the browser (as well as an search engine spiders, etc.) indicating the proper URL to be used.  The `L` flag will indicate that this is the last rule to be run (i.e. do the redirect now don't continue looking at the rest of the .htaccess file).

Note I changed your rule a bit too, such that /lawyer/ would redirect to / and you don't need a trailing slash at the end of the URI (for cases where you might have query strings for example)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is missing the leading `/`, and only matches URLs with `/` on the end. You probably don't want that.

```
RewriteRule ^/lawyer/(.+)$ /$1 [NE]
```

(The NE flag prevents an extra layer of %-escaping being applied, as you're writing to path parts not query segments.)

> I need it to automatically change the url from /lawyer/my-lawyer-profile to /my-lawyer-profile/

If you're saying you want to push the URL displayed in the browser to the shorter version: that's not a rewrite, it's a plain old redirect. You *can* use the R flag to do redirects (as mentioned above), but there's really no need to get out the Swiss Army Chainsaw of mod_rewrite for a simple redirection.

```
Redirect permanent /lawyer /
```